# Page not found error when adding text `2 = 2 ^ 1` to the page

Tags: pages, errors, 404-error

Adding the following text to a page in the Text editor and clicking `Update` results in "Error 404 - Page Not Found":

```
2 = 2^1
```

Replacing this text with anything else makes the Update succeed.

Any ideas what might be causing the error?

**Update:**

After some experimentation I've discovered a more general form of input leading to errors:

```
<number> = <number> ^
```

with the same number on both sides of the equal sign.

For example, `100 = 100 ^` gives an error while `100 = 101 ^` doesn't.

Comment: Whelp, have you tried disabling all your plugins? Have you done nay customization to the website or can we assume it's vanilla?

Comment: I've tried to disable editor-related plugins, but it didn't help. The website is customized.

Comment: Now I've tried disabling all the plugins but still get an error.

Comment: And if you enter any text do you get that error? What about numbers? How about `^`

Comment: I don't get this error with just numbers, `=` or `^`. The error only when they are combined as `2 = 2^1`.

Comment: What are your permalink settings?

Comment: Switch to the default theme. There is probably some broken regex active on your site.

Comment: I have "Post name" in permalink settings and the page already has a valid permalink.

Comment: Switched to the default theme (Twenty Fourteen) but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue when installing mod_security2.

The solution is as simple as disabling mod_security or allowing that page to POST that request.

The issue is that mod_security thinks someone is trying to hack into your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to disable mod_security by adding `<IfModule mod_security.c>SecFilterEngine Off</IfModule>` to `.htaccess`, but it didn't help.

Comment: I would say disabling mod security is overkill. Normal practice is to look up problematic rule in its logs and have that specific rule disabled. Just don't ask me how, that's what I pay managed support for. :)